# how to pass custom args to pm2

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, pm2

these are my scripts:

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon -r dotenv/config index.js dotenv_config_path=../../dev.env",
    "start": "node -r dotenv/config index.js dotenv_config_path=../../prod.env"
  }
```

this is my pm2 config:

```
 {
      name: "api",
      script: "./packages/api/index.js",
      watch: true,
      node_args: "-r dotenv/config",
      args: ["dotenv_config_path=../../dev.env"],
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: "development",
      },
    },
```

the problem is that my `dev.env` file doesn't load.

and this is my folder structure:
[image]

Comment: I was adding -r as args instead of node_args. Your screenshot helped me identify that error.

Comment: I had to upvote your question because after much much searching, your pm2 config was the only one I found on the internet that showed how to correctly specify the env file location.  So thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by changing env file path.